# Could an electron wavefunction wrap multiple times around its orbit?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, atomic-physics, orbitals

In the Bohr model a whole number of electron de Broglie waves with $\lambda=h/mv$ fit around an orbit with radius $r$ so that we have:
$$2\pi r=n\lambda.$$
But could the electron waves wrap around the orbit $m$ times before fitting so that we have the condition:
$$2\pi r m=n\lambda?$$

Here is a representative plot with $n=10$ and $m=3$.

There are three complex amplitudes at each angle $\theta$. The probability of finding the electron at $\theta$ is just the sum of these amplitudes squared.

**Comment**

Actually this idea doesn’t work. If you add these amplitudes together you end up with zero everywhere on the interval $0$ to $2\pi$!

[image: Bohr n=10 m=3]

Comment: 1) Bohr model's correctness had a lot to do with being lucky, and should not be taken as gospel; not least since the correct quantum version thereof is also rather simple. 2) The scheme you are thinking of is not going to work, both for Bohr's model and for quantum theory. 3) The question in the title is not what is in your post; the title is by definition true.

Comment: Is the question (v2) whether a stationary wavefunction is single-valued?

Comment: Is there a wave function in the Bohr model?

Comment: @Qmechanic My question is whether a valid wave function around a circle can be multi-valued at each angle $\theta$.

Answer (score 0):

A simple representations of the group manifold of SO(3,R) is a ball of radius $\pi$, $r$ representing the effective angle of rotation for any axis with direction $\phi,\psi$ on the unit sphere. Clearly antipodes $r=\pm \pi$ have to be identified, so the manifold is  the upper semisphere with equatorial antipodal points identfied.

[image: Rotation Group Manifold]

This is the real obstacle for spin 0 massive charged stable particles to exist in nature, the group manifold is not simply connected.

The Schrödinger theory is a toy theory, only used to represent the scalar unitary representations in the Hilbert space $\mathit L^2(\mathbb R^3)$, that reduces in effect to Bohrs representation of a simple wave of $m$ wavelengths on all circles parallel to the equator, multiplied by a $\sin^m\theta$ factor in order to flatten the function diffentiable at the poles $\theta=0,\pi$  by a zero of order $m$

$$ f(r) Y_{l,l} = f(f) e^{i\ l \ \phi} \ \sin^l \theta $$

and the ladder for $L_z\in (-l,l)$ generated by the ladder operators $L_x\pm i Ly$.

So one may state, that the defining representation of SO(3,R) is not the elementary one, that should be  represented as a simply connected manifold, enabling use of Stokes and Gauss theorems on integrals.

The way out is to extend the ball of radius $\pi$ to $2 \pi$ and declare the geometry such that the outer part $\pi \lt r \le 2pi $ is the antipodal 2- sphere, shrinking with radius, and the complete 2.sphere of radius  $2\pi$ is the point of the negative identity. Implication: No mirror map exists, as it is realized in O(3,R) with two copies of SO(3,R), one semi-ball around the identity, one around -identity.

In the covering map of SU(2,C), local isomorphic to SO(3,R), its clear, that a rotation by $2\pi$ yields a factor $-1$ and after mulriples of $4\pi$ yields  closed loops back to identity.

Group manifolds are free for charting. For SU(2,C), you may consider a fixed axis and a 2-sphere, that changes from outside to inside after a full rotation by $2 \pi$ around any fixed axis.

With paper, glue and scissor, a concentric double sphere is cut on a meridian and inner and outer connected crosswise.

This picture represents the spin 1/2 representations, conventionally represented by a 2-component wave function with odd half integer multiples of the eigenvalue of $j_z$.

Whats different to a scalar theory: The state space is doubled, for free partcles and spherical symmetric bound states, $L_z + s_z$ and $L_z +1 -s_z$ have the same eigenvalue of the roation generator $j_z$.

And a real benefit for approximations: Any component of total angular momentum has half integer spectrum in $\hbar$ units, with the consequence, that a state with central collision $L=0$ with the center is excluded  from Hilbert space.

Why is the double cover spin reprentation working? Simply because in a Hilbert space operator theory, for all measurable expressions, signs, even complex factors of unit norm,  disappear in the unitary bilinear product.

For a two component theory, the bilinearity enables the complete SU(2,C) gauge group as a constant factor.

This gauge group is the source of the electric field, or more generally, of the electro-weak interaction, if its lifted to a space-time dependent field.